# Controlling flow while notifying adapter and firing intent at the same time

Tags: java, android, google-maps, listview, adapter

I am writing an application for a dual screen android device.

I have a method (which is called on the press of a button) which notifies an adapter (displayed on one screen, i.e. on the RightActivity) and then fires an intent to a map displaying on the other screen (i.e. the LeftActivity). The method is as follows :

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    MyAction.fireIntentToMap(context, myList); // fire intent to map on the left screen
    MyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // adapter is for listview displayed on right screen
}
```

What I want is that, the intent should first be fired to the map activity on the left screen, and only after that (i.e. the map displaying the items received in the intent) the list adapter should be notified and the list view should refresh itself.

However, this does not happen. What happens is, that the call goes in the `fireIntenToMap` method and the intent is fired (i.e. a call to `startActivity(intent);` is made. However, before the intent can be received by the map, the line `MyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` executes, and the list view is refreshed. The intent is received later by the map.

Why does this happen? How can I get a single thread behaviour (map processes intent first, then list view is refreshed) here?

.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, you do not have control of when Intent is actually "delivered".

There are several solutions to your problem, but IMO, the most elegant would be to use [ordered broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). So your map and list register (dynamically) to receive your broadcasts, with priority set so that they get called in desired order.

Priority is set via ['intentFilter.setPriority(..)'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29), when you register for receiving broadcasts via ['Context.registerReceiver(..)'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29).

Then you trigger the broadcast with [`Context.sendOrderedBroadcast(..)'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not firing an intent to `MyListAdapter` . I'm only calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it.